# preg_match fails in php > 5.3

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm not good with regular expression, so I don't even know what this one does, exactly:

```
echo preg_match('/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\x2d]{1,63}\x2e)*[a-zA-Z0-9\x2d]{1,63}){1,254}$/', 'example12345678.com>');
```

I took it from an older version of Zend Framework - 1.5, which is outdated and in the last stable version of the framework this regexp is no longer presented. However, its behavior is curious, because I found no documented explanation or a backward incompatibility note in the official php resources.

The thing is that on php 5.2.* it works fine: returns 0. On php 5.3.10, 5.4.0 (most likely 5.3.*, 5.4.* I presume) it returns FALSE, meaning "an error".

My question is: why? and what is the error? Is it the regexp, some kind of recursion or rules ambiguity? Why it works on php 5.2 if so?

---

Interestingly enough, if I change 'example12345678.com>' to 'example1234567.com>' (making it one or more char shorter) - it starts working and returns 0. If I change it to '123123123123123123123123123' it works too and returns 1.

**UPD**: don't know yet if this matters but pcre versions here are 8.02 (php 5.2) vs 8.12 (php 5.3)

---

**UPD2**: I do understand what it's for... more or less... and there is no problem with getting anything working right now. As I said - a Zend_Validate_* update solves it. I'll try to describe my concern in other words:

say, I upgrade an important piece of software, making php5.2 > php5.3 switch. I try to find information on all problems I could face (Mostly by reading this: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php). The software is a bit old, but it's not ancient, e.g. Zend Framework could be of version 1.5. I check/patch/analyze and fix every bc break and deprecated feature. Even my unit tests run fine.

To my surprise what is described in the question happens. (To be precise, Zend_Validate_Hostname there throws an exception). So now I want to know why I missed this one when upgrading and, what's more important, whether I should recheck all 'preg_match' (and other PCRE utilizing functions) in the app trying various imaginable input data in attempt to find similar "bug fixes".

If it is a "bug fix". Because it looks like a new bug - it used to work as expected in php5.2 and doesn't work anymore.

Was hoping to get some clues to narrow down the search.

Comment: How are you using it if you don't know what it does, exactly?

Comment: And from what file did you take it?

Comment: @ilanco, I'm using it as a part of the framework. this is offtopic however.

Comment: Depends more on your `PCRE_VERSION` than the `phpversion()`.

Comment: @TheGuyOfDoom, this was taken from \Zend\Validate\Hostname.php (which is being used when validating email addresses using Zend_Validate_EmailAddress)

Comment: @mario, makes sense. I'd have to build and compile with an external pcre to check that (or just use it directly). Will see about that. Will check their changelog as well. thank you for your comment.

Comment: Is the `>` necessary in your example string? Your preg_match will always return false if there's a `>` in the string as far as I can see.

Comment: @FabricioMatte, unfortunately it is :) Notice it will work with php5.2 (pcre 8.02). This is based on a real case, real unexpected problem when going 5.2 > 5.3)

Comment: That string does not match that regular expression; if it succeeded in PHP 5.2, that was a bug.  Whatever else may be the case, strings matching that regex have to end in a letter, a digit, or a hyphen.  And nothing else.  So you need to fix either the regex or the string you're submitting.

Comment: @MarkReed. "Not matching" should return 0. It does return 0 in php 5.2. In php 5.3 it returns FALSE (means error). Why? (reread the question ;))

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  So it's returning an error.  What's the error?  What does `preg_last_error()` say?

Comment: `preg_last_error()` returns `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`. Very interesting. This happens with **example1234567q.com>** as well, btw.

Comment: Yeah, too many levels.  Check my answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

That is an ugly regular expression.  The problem is, there are too many ways that the string *might* match, and so the engine is running out of memory trying them all before it figures out that it doesn't actually match.

Also, it looks like it's trying to match valid domain names, and it doesn't.  I would replace that call to `preg_match` with a call to this function instead:

```
function is_valid_domain_name($string) {
    if (strlen($string) > 253) {
        return false;
    }
    $label = '(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}(?<!-)';
    return preg_match("/^(?:$label\.){0,126}$label$/", $string);
}
```

It fails quickly on your problem string:

```
echo is_valid_domain_name('example12345678.com>'),"\n";
```

Comment: This is ugly indeed. Like most other regular expressions. :) Thank you for your answer Mark. The problem with this particular regexp was solved, however. What I asked about was: why did it work with php5.2? I updated my question with some details.

Comment: You're never going to catch everything in an upgrade, no mater how careful you are.  If you'd had a test that happened to trigger this problem, great, but you didn't. You just have to be ready to iterate and fix what you find broken afterwards.  I'm guessing there was a change in the pcre engine which set a tighter constraint (or maybe just a constraint where there previously wasn't one) to try and avoid infinite-recursion problems.

Comment: You're right, I can't catch everything. But I can try to catch as much as possible. And those things I do catch must have an explanation, something real, not just "oh, sigh, bad luck, what you gonna do". If this is a bug, I could report it, if this is a feature we could add it to the backwards incompatibilities list.

Comment: It's a *difference*, and whether it's a bug or a feature depends on your use case. :)

Comment: i have also faced same error (if content is too long in second argument then it will be stuck and return empty...)